# Compare against each value in a Json encoded array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, json

How can compare each a from content `json_encode` that inserted in database with a string as shorthand code without use loop? (this values was checkbox that inserted in database with `json_encode`)

**Example**

```
$json_encode = ["how", "are", "hello", "what"];

echo ($json_encode == 'hello') ? 'It is true' :'';
```

Comment: Can you clarify, I've read the question a few times but Im afraid it isnt too clear what you specifically want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a little bit of a 'round a bout' way of doing things but this should do the trick:

```
$json_encode = '["how", "are", "hello", "what"]';    
echo ( in_array('hello', json_decode($json_encode)) ? 'It is true' :'' );
```

Your initial $json_encode isnt setup correctly as a proper JSON string, and required decoding to use the array checking functionality later on.

A better approach maybe:

```
$json_string = json_encode(array("how", "are", "hello", "what"));
echo ( in_array('hello', json_decode($json_string )) ? 'It is true' :'' );
```

Answer (score 0):

try with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

```
$json_encode = ["how", "are", "hello", "what"];

echo ( in_array('hello', $json_encode) ? 'It is true' :'' );
```